# AVPlayer seekToTime not working correctly

Tags: avplayer

I made a demo for using AVPlayer with Obj-c, I'm having trouble getting the seek feature to work. It looks like it's working if current stream didn't exceed 30 seconds, but if called after that time won't get back ..

Appreciate if you check my [demo](https://github.com/TomerGlick/AVPlayerDemo) project on [GITHUB](https://github.com/TomerGlick/AVPlayerDemo) to figure what's the problem..

See class named StreamManager and function -seekInTimeBackward for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to play your **URL** in Safari and it does play but says its **live broadcast** and does not allow your to seek, same with Chrome browser and I also tried to play it with my own AVPlayer on iPhone and it does not seek.

It simply mean that we can not seek live broadcast.

Comment: I thought that AVPlayer "records" using buffer so I could use seek, so is there another way to accomplish seek when using live broadcasts ?